# Redefine global JIT function and maintain performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, numba

I'm in the process of developing a PDE package (similar to [fenics](https://fenicsproject.org/)) and am trying to come up with the best way for a user to define their functions. The current method I am using is fine. However, as the package grows the run-time compilation of the functions will take much longer.

The current method takes in a dictionary of function specs and redefines and recompiles the global default. As the package gets larger, it would be ideal if I could have everything compiled ahead of time; the problem is for numba's `pycc` AOT compilation, you can't pass in a function because there is no recognizable signature type (that I could find in the documentaion). I have also tried using `cython` but the function stays as a weak reference to a pyobject which ruins the performance.

The code in the module where the function exists looks like

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit
def _user_defined_function(z, t):
    return -z


def define_vector_func(func_specs, **numba_kwargs):
    # func_specs is a dict, numba_kwargs are for jit decorator

    # create a string to be compiled into a new function
    exprs = []
    for var in func_specs:
        s = func_specs[var]
        for i, (variable, expression) in enumerate(func_specs.items()):
            s = s.replace(variable, f'z[{i}]')
        exprs.append(s)

    fp = '<ipython-cache-safe>'  # needed to allow for caching
    src = ', '.join(exprs)
    src = f'def local_func(z, t): return np.array([{src}])\n'
    lines = [src]
    linecache.cache[fp] = (len(src), None, lines, fp)
    code = compile(src, fp, 'exec')
    exec(code)

    # redefine global function and return a reference if user wants to use it
    local_func_ptr = vars()['local_func']
    local_func_ptr(np.ones(len(func_specs)), 0.0)
    global _user_defined_function
    _user_defined_function = njit(**numba_kwargs)(local_func_ptr)
    _rec()  # recompile other functions to recognize new function
    return _user_defined_function

# rest of module
# ...
```

To use it from a separate module, you would do something like

```
from module_above import define_vector_func, other_funcs_from_module

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_spec = {'v': 'v - (v * v * v) / 3.0 - w + 0.08',
                 'w': '0.08 * (v - 0.8 * w + 0.7)'}

    f = define_vector_func(func_spec, fastmath=True, cache=True)
    # do what user wants
```

What would be the best route for compiling the module ahead of time and maintain performance?